# Update values for a column if it matches the values for another column on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have one table that looks like this:

```
VisitID CustomerID  OTHER COLUMNS...
1   11
1   11
1   NULL
1   NULL
1   11
2   22
2   NULL
2   22
2   NULL
```

The table is huge and there are way more rows. What I would like to do is to UPDATE the table, assigning the same value for the NULLs if the value matches with column VisitID.

Expected output:

```
VisitID CustomerID
1   11
1   11
1   11
1   11
1   11
2   22
2   22
2   22
2   22
```

Any insights?

OBS: I cannot just drop the NULL rows because there are other columns with different values assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just use an updateable CTE here to get the `MAX` value for `CustomerID` and then `UPDATE` rows with a value of `NULL`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CustomerID,
           MAX(CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID) AS MaxCustomerID
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET CustomerID = MaxCustomerID
WHERE CustomerID IS NULL;
```

If a given value of `VisitID` van have 2 or more non-`NULL` values this any `NULL` values would (obviously) be assigned the `MAX` value of those values. For example, if you had a `VisitID` of 3, where 1 row had the value `12` for `CustomerID`, other `13` and then there were 3 rows with the value `NULL`, those 3 rows would have the value `13` assigned to them (meaning 4 rows with the value `13` and 1 with `12`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimal solution using the aggregate function `MAX()` :

```
UPDATE t
SET CustomerID = max_CustomerID
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT VisitID, MAX(CustomerID) AS max_CustomerID
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY VisitID
  HAVING SUM(IIF(CustomerID IS NULL, 1, 0)) > 0
) AS s ON s.VisitID = t.VisitID
WHERE CustomerID IS NULL;
```

The `HAVING` clause will remove IDs with complete data, leaving just the ones that require update.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ivgdkKZG)